# Dividing by huge numbers in haskell

Tags: haskell

How do I get a number in decimal format when performing 1/200!

```
Prelude>factorial x = product([1..x])
Prelude>x = factorial 200
Prelude>1/x
0.0
```

Comment: You probably better would use fractions for this, and *not* floating points.

Comment: I suspect you'll want to use an integer logarithm to get a sense of the order of magnitude of `200!` and then go from there, but I can't get into the full details right now.

Comment: Completely unrelated, but this reminds me of a fun programming puzzle: write a function which takes `n` and computes the number of trailing zeros in `n!`. It can be done very efficiently indeed and doesn't require bignum computations until seriously large `n`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [CReal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.1/docs/Data-Number-CReal.html):

```
Data.Number.CReal> showCReal 400 (1/product [1..200])
"0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012679769534809624217530164"
Data.Number.CReal> showCReal 30 (1e375/product [1..200])
"1.267976953480962421753016371075"
```

The `400`/`30` there is how many digits to show.

If you like the speed of `Double`, you could consider scaling each number before computing the product.

```
>  product (map (100/) [1..200])
1.2679769534809638e25
```

That requires a bit of reinterpretation of the output, though.

Comment: I like your `CReal` answer. I don't understand your answer about `Double`s. What are you doing there? What's it mean in the end? Can it be fixed up by counting?

Comment: @dfeuer At the end, it's off by a factor of 10^400 (=100^200) exactly (plus rounding errors, I guess), so you just need to read the `e25` as `e-375` instead.